# How ENTRYPOINT and CMD works between base and current image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

`somedockerhub/backend-base` has  `ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]`

where `entrypoint.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /appenv/bin/activate
exec $@
```

---

Below is the docker-compose file:

```
app:
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/release/Dockerfile
  links:
    - dbc
  volumes_from:
    - webroot
  environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: todobackend.settings.release
    MYSQL_HOST: db
    MYSQL_USER: user1
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: passwd
  command:
    - uwsgi
    - "--socket /var/www/someapp/someapp.sock"
    - "--chmod-socket=666"
    - "--module someapp.wsgi"
    - "--master"
    - "--die-on-term"
```

---

where `docker/release/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM somedockerhub/backend-base:latest


# Copy application artifacts
COPY target /wheelhouse

# Install application
RUN . /appenv/bin/activate && \
    pip install --no-index -f /wheelhouse someapp
    rm -rf /wheelhouse

ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]
```

---

1)

For container launched by `app` service

Does `ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]` get executed before `ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]`?

2)

Assume there is no entry point in current image,  does current image execute base image entry point and then
 `command` instruction launch `uwsgi` process with pid 1?

Comment: Just to add, there is no `CMD` instruction in base image and current image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For container launched by app service
>
> Does ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"] get executed before ENTRYPOINT
>   ["echo"]?

No, `ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]` overrides `ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]` of the base image.

So `ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]` will run and it will receive:

`command:
    - uwsgi
    - "--socket /var/www/someapp/someapp.sock"
    - "--chmod-socket=666"
    - "--module someapp.wsgi"
    - "--master"
    - "--die-on-term"`

as argument

> Assume there is no entry point in current image, does current image
>   execute base image entry point and then  command instruction launch
>   uwsgi process with pid 1?

Yes `entrypoint.sh` will run. It will receive `command` value as argument.

`entrypoint` code `exec $@` means: execute all the script (`enterypoint.sh`) arguments `(uwsgi...)`.

`exec` by [definition](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/exec.htm) doesn't generate new process, rather loads `uwsgi` into memory of existing process. Because `exec` process is launched with pid 1, `uwsgi` will receive pid 1.

Comment: Just to further understand... If current image does not have entry point instruction? Does current image run base image entry point?

Comment: My second question is in this context... Query edited

Comment: answered your question

Comment: One more issue with dockerfile - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58479409/3317808