# Dockerfile - Unexpected token error in mocha

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, mocha.js, dockerfile

Below is the dockerfile which is stored as image tag `somehub/someapp-specs`:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

MAINTAINER Developer team <developerteam@abc.com>

# Prevent dpkg source
ENV TERM=xterm-256color

# Set mirrors to ca
RUN sed -i "s/http:\/\/archive./http:\/\/ca.archive./g" /etc/apt/sources.list

# Install node.js
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install curl -y && \
    curl -sL http://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install application dependencies
RUN npm install -g mocha && \
    npm install

# Set mocha test runner as entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["mocha"]
```

---

which is used in `test` service in below snipper of docker-compose:

```
test:
  image: somehub/someapp-specs
  links:
    - nginx
  environment:
    URL: http://nginx:8080/todos
    JUNIT_REPORT_PATH: /reports/acceptance.xml
    JUNIT_REPORT_STACK: 1
  command: --reporter mocha-jenkins-reporter
```

---

that launched  `mocha` container with error:

```
$ docker-compose up test
release_dbc_1 is up-to-date
Starting release_webroot_1 ... done
Creating release_app_1     ... done
Creating release_nginx_1   ... done
Creating release_test_1    ... done
Attaching to release_test_1
test_1     | /usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha:13
test_1     | const {deprecate, warn} = require('../lib/utils');
test_1     |       ^
test_1     | 
test_1     | SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
test_1     |     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
test_1     |     at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
test_1     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
test_1     |     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
test_1     |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
test_1     |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
test_1     |     at startup (node.js:140:18)
test_1     |     at node.js:1043:3
release_test_1 exited with code 1
```

---

`COPY . /app` instruction in Dockerfile is copying package.json with below versions:

```
{
  "name": "someappspecs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "someapp acceptance tests",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "xyz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.7.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "mocha": "^6.2.1",
    "mocha-jenkins-reporter": "^0.4.2",
    "superagent": "^5.1.0",
    "superagent-promise": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

---

`mocha` is used to run acceptance tests on `release_app_1` container

How to resolve this unexpected token error? looks unrelated with other container service.

Comment: What version of node is running that? It looks like it might not be recognising the object destructuring syntax.

Comment: @david Query edited with package.json. I think it is node 4. I updated with belo changes.. testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Mocha require node >6.0 but yours 4.x

> As of v6.0.0, Mocha requires Node.js v6.0.0 or newer.

Try to upgrade your node by using Node image:

```
FROM node:10.16
```

or you can update your current dockerfile like so:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install curl -y && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: In package.json, are the Verizon's of tools matching with node 6

Comment: I'm not sure, it's depend on your Node version on your development mode. It should be the same as this one so that everything will be consistent

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found` after your recommended changes `FROM node:10.16`

Comment: Sorry, I copied it from the question. Remove sudo should works. Answer updated. @overexchange